# enum as template argument for base class always fails with unresolved errors

Tags: c++

I have an `Enum` and  simple base class that looks like this,

```
enum E
   {
     a,
     b
   };
 template<E e> 
   struct Base
   {
     static int i;
   };
```

and its children,

```
 struct CC
   {
     template<E e, class T>
     struct C;
     template<class T>
     struct C<a, T> : Base<a>
     {
       void Do(int i)
       {  
         Base<a>::i=i;
       }
     };

     template<class T>
     struct C<b, T> : Base<b>
     {
       void Do(int i)
       {  
          Base<b>::i=i;
       }
     };

     template<E e, typename T>
     void Do(int i)
     {
        C<e,T>->Do(i);
     } 
};
```

I want to  call `Do` in either one of the two structs specialized by an enum value passed in the template. If it is `E::a` then call `Do` of `C<a>` or of `C<b>` otherwise.
The errors I got after Build is `"Unresolved External Symbol Base<0>::i ...."`

Comment: `template<class T> struct C<a> : Base<a>` should be `template<class T> struct C<a, T> : Base<a>`, same for `struct C<b>`

Comment: Yes, thank you I edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `static` class member variables.

Write this at a file scope:

```
int Base<a>::i;
int Base<b>::i;
```

From [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Explanation):

> The `static` keyword is only used with the declaration of a static member, inside the class definition, but not with the definition of that static member:
>
> ```
> class X { static int n; }; // declaration (uses 'static')
> int X::n = 1;              // definition (does not use 'static')
> ```
>
> **The declaration inside the class body is not a definition** and may declare the member to be of incomplete type (other than `void`), including the type in which the member is declared:

Comment: Thanks but I still have error at the external `Do` method. The program can't see CC's `Do`. I want to call `Do` of one of the two nested structs without marking any as `static` method or using base class pointer.

Comment: @DaWei It's not declared as `static` so you need an instance of the class to call the function. i.e. `CC x; x.Do<a, int>();`